# Huffman coding - conditions for perfect tree output

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, trees

The question is: Given 4 characters and their frequencies, what's the max possible difference between the frequency of the rarest character and that of the most common character, so the output Huffman tree is a perfect tree (all 4 leaves are the same depth)?

**My direction:** let's call the frequencies **A, B, C ,D** so that **A** is the frequency of the most common character and **D** is that of the rariest character.
so that **D < C < B < A**.

So **C** and **D** will be merged first.

```
      C + D
     /     \
    C       D
```

Now in order to get a perfect tree we need **A**  and **B** to be merged separately in the next step.

```
      A + B
     /     \
    A       B
```

(as opposed to **B** been merged with **C+D** resulting in a not perfect tree)

and then we get.

```
                       A + B + C + D
                       /          \
                    C + D        A + B  
                   /     \       /    \
                  C       D     A      B
```

But I can't formulate anything...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have the symbols $A,B,C,D$ ordered by probabilities: $P_A\ge P_B \ge P_C \ge P_D \ge0$.

The Huffman algorithm constructs the code by succesively merging the two symbols with lowest probabilities (reorder and repeat). In order to have a perfect binary tree (same depth for all leaves -in this case: to have all codes with length two) we need that the first merge produces a probability greater than $A$ (so it goes to the first position - otherwise, the code for $A$ would have only one bit) - this is necessary and sufficient. Hence we need

$$P_C + P_D \ge P_A$$

To bound $P_C$: $P_C+P_B+P_A\le 1$ and because $P_C$ is the minimum of those, then $P_C\le 1/3$. Hence
$$  P_A - P_D \le \frac{1}{3}$$

It's easy to see that this bound is tight: just take $P_A= P_B=P_C=1/3$

Comment: So all of the other frequencies have to be 1/3 of PA so that we can get the max difference.. Thank you!

Comment: NOt "1/3 of PA" but "1/3"

Comment: yes what i said in the first comment was wrong but isn't it true that the other frequencies can't be more then 3 time Pa? I mean, I wanted to bound the difference between Pa and Pd.. Or you're saying that they all can't be more then a third of the sum of frequencies? because you assume Pd -> 0?

Comment: I don't get you. The difference between Pa and Pd is bounded by 1/3, as I wrote. "The other frequencies" (Pb and Pc) must be less or equal than P_a (we started from that).

Comment: This answer is not correct. When there are ties, the Huffman algorithm has the option to pick any of the pairs for the next step. Therefore the top three being exactly 1/3 does _not_ assure a perfect tree. You don't have to combine A and B in the next step. You can just as well combine A and CD or B and CD, resulting in an imperfect tree. Also those probabilities for A, B, and C gives that P_D is identically 0. In that case, any self-respecting implementation of the Huffman algorithm will not code the symbol D at all! You will then get a coding of three symbols, which cannot be perfect.